# Dreamweaver Uploading

Tags: workflow, dreamweaver

When we work on websites, sometimes the PSD files save in the HTML/Images folder of the project. We usually upload HTML folder to the server through Dreamweaver. Is there a way we can tell Dreamweaver to not upload PSD files?

Comment: I'm fairly sure I remember Dreamweaver having ability to filter its upload/sync by file type. If not, full-blown FTP clients certainly do. But unfortunateky I don't think this can be described as a graphic design question.

Comment: oh I thought this is the right place to ask this question, may be because I found the Dreamweaver tag in questions page. There are several other people asked the questions related to Dreamweaver, which encourages me to ask this question. Any how I will be careful next time

Comment: @e100 - I think it's valid as a workflow question.

Comment: But the workflow is broken if you are using Photoshop generated HTML ;)

Comment: Can't you just...move the PSD files to another folder?

Comment: On reflection, I agree this is a fair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "cloaking," and Dreamweaver does this. Get into the Site Setup Dialog (there are different ways to do this; you can right click a single file and look for cloaking, or do it through the menu for the Files palette:

[image: Getting into the Cloaking dialog in Dreamweaver]

Once you're in Advanced Settings > Cloaking, you can set options to cloak a certain file format:

[image: Cloaking dialog in Dreamweaver]

Or you can right-click individual files and exclude them that way.

[Here's a link to Adobe's documentation for more on the matter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7e9fa.html). [This Adobe DevNet page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/first_website_pt6.html) also gives some insight.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have seen this option several times but never bother to check it. Now I can leave my PSDS into Images folder. I like to keep the PSD into images folder because when we save its png or jpg through save as it directly opens the folder of the PSD file.

Comment: You are way better off saving your psd in a different directory with a shortcut to the web directory placed in it, so you can just hit that link to drop them in the web directory. That way you won't wind up with issues like this at all, and you can still easily save your web output to the webserver.